# Can I use Azure Data Factory for ETL Testing as well?

Tags: azure-data-factory

If I have to do data migration and ETL testing for data in Azure SQL DB's then can I use Azure Data Factory?

If yes the please provide some links explaining how? or some tutorials or page where I can find some details?

Thanks in advance!
Sunil

Comment: Can you explain and give examples of what kind of testing would you like to do?

Comment: I need to do ETL Testing: 1. Make sure that all the tables are moved from Source to target DB. 2. test data all the rows of a given tables is moved from source to target table. 3. test that schema is correct 4. test that transformation is done correctly during ETL process and the target DB tables has the correct column and rows etc..

Comment: Could you please provide your approach if any followed?

Comment: I didn't follow any specific approach but found this and need to while trying it's difficult to follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2PkwNqxj1E&list=PLMWaZteqtEaLacN3eS3s8pw2jtwBVb1BH&index=36

If I have 100s of tables and more than 70 columns in some table then it'll be tedious task to do that in ADF so want to know is it worth or is there any marketplace solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do ETL testing by using data factory. I copied all tables from one database to another database by using below process:
I check all the tables by using below command:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.

TABLES Where TABLE_TYPE =  'BASE TABLE'  and TABLE_SCHEMA =  'dbo'
```

[image]

I created pipeline and performed Lookup activity to retrieve the tables of database by entering below query.

[image]

Output:

[image]

I created linked service for source and sink on success of lookup activity I implemented foreach activity by enabling sequential and added copy activity to it. I created dynamic dataset by using linked service that created for source. to retrieve all the tables from database I added the data dynamically as below:

[image]

Created schema and table parameters enter dynamic content for schema is `@dataset().schema`  and for table is `@dataset().table`  entered values for schema is `@item().TABLE_SCHEMA` for table is `@item().TABLE_NAME` .

[image]

create dataset by using linked service that created for sink and created parameters and entered values same as source in the sink and enabled auto create table option.

[image]

Executed the pipeline. It executed successfully.

[image]

All tables are copied to target database.

[image]

In this way you can   copy all the tables from one database to another database.

Comment: Here, my query is, after coping the data from source to destination can I verify that:
1. Verify the Data in Table-1 from source DB tables matches with Table-1 in target DB
2. Verify the count of rows in Table-1 from source DB table is matching with Table-1 in target DB
3. Find if there are any missing rows in target DB table w.r.t. source db table
4. basically, I want to do complete ETL Testing - where I would like to check transformed data as well

Comment: By using Azure data factory you can know how many rows are copied and how many table are getting tables to target , to test your requirements you should you use third party ETL testing tools.